# Regular expressions - find all linebreaks not after a ","

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex drive me crazy... can you help me?

I need a **Regex that find all line breaks, if there are not after a comma**.

I tried this:

```
((?!\,)\n)
```

But he match all line breaks.

What I want to do this: Transform a JSON (String with line breaks)

```
[
 {
  "username": "tim",
  "comment": "you doing a great job!"
 },
 {
  "username": "tim",
  "comment": "when you have new workshoppers?"
 }
]
```

to:

```
[ { "username": "tim",
  "comment": "you doing a great job!" },
 { "username": "tim",
  "comment": "when you have new workshoppers?" } ]
```

So I tried to replace all line breaks not after a "," with "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing lookaheads and lookbehinds.

- `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead
- `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind

So what you actually need is a negative lookbehind.

JavaScript does not support lookbehinds though. A workaround could be replacing `([^,])[\r\n]+` by `$1`.

See [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/fD1uQ3/1).

Comment: regex in JavaScript does not support `(?<!...)`

Comment: js won't support look-behinds.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed the OP was using JS, I updated.

Comment: @user3351722 Glad I could help ;) Don't hesite to use [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/), a great tool helping creating/debugging regexes.